# Compile consecutive non-NA values across time

Tags: r

I have a df with many observations and 124 columns, the last 119 of which are consecutive months beginning in Feb. 2005 and ending in Nov. 2014. Each row consists of an identifying code, a start month (yearmon form), and then three columns of model results: the value, the model-predicted value, and the residual. The rest are the months, as mentioned. I tried to provide the first 100 rows of this below - apologies but the dput is too long with the 119 date columns.

For each code/starting month, there are values for the twelve months after the start month. So for instance, my first row has a start month of Jan 2012, so the month columns are all NAs except for the Feb 2012-Jan 2013 columns. The next row is the same code and start month is Feb 2012 (different model results), so March 2012-Feb 2013 columns have values, and all else is NA.

I cannot figure out how to aggregate the non-NA columns to just have the 12 values that are populated for each row. The goal is to eventually run a cumulative product function on the months with values down the df, but I only need the 12 columns that matter for each.

Is there a good function that somehow standardizes regardless of the actual month (column) and will provide those same five starting columns and then 12 columns of the needed values that always differ?

There's also a complicating factor that not all of these rows have 12 consecutive months filled. For instance, there may be no value in the 4th month of the 12-month series, but there are still only 12 months that COULD have values in them for that row.

Thank you very much.

EDIT: A sample of the dataframe:

```
structure(list(code = c("qqq", "qqq", "qqq", "qqq", "qqq", "qqq", 
"qqq", "qqq", "qqq", "qqq"), startmonth = structure(c(2012, 2012.08333333333, 
2012.16666666667, 2012.25, 2012.33333333333, 2012.41666666667, 
2012.5, 2012.58333333333, 2012.66666666667, 2012.75), class = "yearmon"), 
actual = c(531.8070679, 481.1286926, 466.6588745, 503.1075134, 
569.5734863, 569.586792, 586.2329102, 561.9111328, 499.8103027, 
498.1677856), model = c(686.9315941, 642.5716051, 616.4195817, 
639.1987258, 684.4228377, 671.7456088, 669.476986, 649.4140804, 
606.2803121, 557.0674166), residual = c(-155.1245262, -161.4429125, 
-149.7607072, -136.0912124, -114.8493514, -102.1588168, -83.24407583, 
-87.50294761, -106.4700094, -58.89963098), `Dec 2012` = c("3.314476013", 
"3.314476013", "3.314476013", "3.314476013", "3.314476013", 
"3.314476013", "3.314476013", "3.314476013", "3.314476013", 
"3.314476013"), `Jan 2013` = c("2.016448021", "2.016448021", 
"2.016448021", "2.016448021", "2.016448021", "2.016448021", 
"2.016448021", "2.016448021", "2.016448021", "2.016448021"
), `Feb 2013` = c(NA, "0.041545", "0.041545", "0.041545", 
"0.041545", "0.041545", "0.041545", "0.041545", "0.041545", 
"0.041545"), `Mar 2013` = c(NA, NA, "1.944175005", "1.944175005", 
"1.944175005", "1.944175005", "1.944175005", "1.944175005", 
"1.944175005", "1.944175005"), `Apr 2013` = c(NA, NA, NA, 
"0.898332", "0.898332", "0.898332", "0.898332", "0.898332", 
"0.898332", "0.898332"), `May 2013` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "1.043239951", 
"1.043239951", "1.043239951", "1.043239951", "1.043239951", 
"1.043239951"), `Jun 2013` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "0.722914994", 
"0.722914994", "0.722914994", "0.722914994", "0.722914994"
), `Jul 2013` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "-0.349180996", 
"-0.349180996", "-0.349180996", "-0.349180996"), `Aug 2013` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "0.074822001", "0.074822001", "0.074822001"
), `Sep 2013` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "-1.258324027", 
"-1.258324027"), `Oct 2013` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "1.153113008")), .Names = c("code", "startmonth", 
"actual", "model", "residual", "Dec 2012", "Jan 2013", "Feb 2013", 
"Mar 2013", "Apr 2013", "May 2013", "Jun 2013", "Jul 2013", "Aug 2013", 
"Sep 2013", "Oct 2013"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It is generally not sufficient to just *describe* your data set - please add some actual data (e.g. using `dput`) to make you example reproducible.

Comment: try `dput(droplevels(mydata[1:10, 1:20]))` and post the exact output from the console into the question without modification.

Comment: Thank you. That worked great, edit made above.

Comment: It worked, but apparently it was a bad choice of columns since they are all NA only.. perhaps you can modify the column selection so that there are also some with data in it.. for example `dput(droplevels(mydata[1:10, c(1:5, 40:60)]))`

Comment: Got it, it should have values now.

Comment: Cumulative product on factors that have a varying number of negative values seems like to create garbage.

Comment: The products would be taken on each individual row.

Comment: Check out the `naLast` function in the the SOfun package available via github: https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun. Apply this by row on your data except the first few columns, then delete those that remain with NAs only. Cbind the first columns to it and you should have what you are looking for (in theory, at least).

Comment: (Untagged [tag:df]; note that tag's for the Unix disk-free command, not dataframe)